# Should I seed DB in DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or in DbMigrationsConfiguration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a working code first entity model with a model change policy in place:

```
public class MyModelChangePolicy : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDBContext context)
    {
        //Add the enumeration type values
        context.SyncEnums(false);
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

`SyncEnums` is an extension method I created which loads data into several enumeration type tables.

Now I am working to add code first migrations to my project. I am using [this guide over at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx). The Configuration.cs has been added under the Migrations folder. But it has a `Seed` method as well. Here is the auto-generated code:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyDBContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
    }
}
```

I am new to code first and this is the first migration plan I have created. My question is: what is the difference between these 2 seed methods? And which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method will seed your database if, and only if, the database is dropped and recreated during a migration.  The second option will seed your database every time a migration is run, regardless of whether the database was dropped and recreated.  Personally, I put my environment-agnostic database "constants" in Configuration.Seed.  Then again, I *never* drop and recreate our databases as part of our deployments (even in our dev environment).  I hope this helps.

Comment: With your answer, along with a couple of other things I found, I think I am understanding better now. The Drop/Create worked well for me when I was doing my initial database build. Now that I've got a project up and running and real production data in place, I think I should remove the drop/create policy and switch to using migrations.

Comment: Glad I could help. Code First EF takes a little getting used to, but I really love it.